# How to use mavensmate v7.0?

Tags: ide, mavensmate, sublime

This morning, I got an error message in sublime editor saying that I need to have MavensMate Desktop installed and running and later realized that there was a new release for MavensMate-SublimeText released three days [ago](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/releases) (My sublime might have auto upgraded to the latest release of MavensMate-SublimeText without my knowledge)

I had to install the [MavensMate-Desktop](https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate-desktop/releases) which is **now mandatory** to use mavensmate plugin for sublime but looks like I always need to have two windows(MavensMate UI and Sublime) running to make any changes to a apex class or anything.

Am I missing something? or Is this how it is supposed to work?

Also how do I go back to the old release?

**Note:** I thought this is the right forum to post this kind of question rather than on the MavensMate github project..so please don't close as off-topic.

Comment: Technically this is not on topic for SFSE as it is related to external tools, however, since many users are affected by this in the SF community I am not going to vote to close it. To work with TLS 1.1 you must be using v7 or change to alternate tools like IlluminatedCloud, Cloud9.io, etc. You have options at least

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same. I found [Issue #769](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/issues/769) instructive.

> **joeferraro** commented on Apr 12
> Hey guys, so it doesn't look particularly straightforward to support TLS 1.1 in the Python-based mm tool. In the meantime, we're recommending folks use the node-based betas: https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText#version-7-betas
>
> **hemmeter** commented on Apr 12
> Upgraded to version 7 betas did the trick
>
> ...
>
> **sameersheikh** commented on Jun 27
> @Jeremywhiteley - I have found how to do it ( I have done on my Mac Machine, so if you are on windows I believe its pretty much the same too)
>
> When you get the error for TLS, the first thing you need to do is:
>
> **Step 1:**
> Go to Mavensmate tab on sublime Text --> Settings --> User Plugin Settings. Open it in sublime
>
> On the file set the value true as shown in code below from the same file By default your machine will install the Mavensmate-app on the below default directories(I assume):
>
> //set to true if you would like to automatically start MavensMate-app when Sublime Text opens
> "mm_start_mavensmate_app" : **true,
>
> ```
> // set to full path of MavensMate-app (MavensMate.app on OSX, MavensMate.exe on Windows, etc.)
> "mm_mavensmate_app_location" : {
>     "osx": "/Applications/MavensMate.app",
>     "windows": "C:\\Program Files\\MavensMate.exe",
>     "linux": ""
> },**
> ```
>
> **Step 2:**
> Download and Install Mavesmate-app from the url. Choose according to your operating system:
>
> https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate-app/releases
>
> **Step 3:**
> Once Installed, open the MavensMate app from the installed apps and go to the app Settings by click right top bars. Set your Workspace (Copy it exactly and change your name whereever you have installed it) : ["/Users/Jeremy.xyz/workspace"]
>
> Once entered, click on the app anywhere to make sure it has saved the settings. Restart your sublime.
>
> **Please make a note that the Mavensmate app needs to be running along side your sublime in order to work.** [my emphasis]

Comment: Are you using OSX? I am on linux and these instructions are not working. https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/blob/master/util.py -- Here on line 53 it is just mentioned as TODO so I guess the launch mavensmate app on sublime startup thing is not working on linux. Thanks!

Comment: @javanoob I am indeed on OSX. You have to be very careful about your path variables. I'm not sure how to interpret that link you posted.

Comment: The setting you mentioned on step 2 is actually very helpful and without that you have to open the Mavensmate App manually every time we launch sublime. I gave my mavensmate app installation location(in my case it is linux) but I was running into an error. Because Mavensmate is opensource, I started looking into the code to see why it is failing and that is when I realized the code to launch MavensMate app for linux platform is not yet implemented. In the above link you can see on line 53 that it is not yet implemented. Lucky you for being on Mac :)

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the git repo there are zip files for the app depending on the OS you use

https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Desktop/releases

Download and simple install this .

Once you install you have to keep this open always and keep it running .

You can go back to previous release by uninstalling mavensmate and then installing the previous release and also in settings you can switch off the auto upgrade .

Comment: Keep in mind that going back to the previous version of MM will not work in sandboxes as it does not work with the disabling of TLS 1.0 in sandboxes. In order to use TLS 1.1 or higher you must use the new version of MM/Sublime. And this all happened when Joe left the project for a while due to family (Understandable) and v7 was in beta and unstable. Good thing though as I switched to Idea and Illuminated cloud which is a dream compared to Sublime that I loved for so many years

Comment: I have moved to Visualstudio Code Editor with a free plugin build by one of colleague https://github.com/celador/ForceCode .The good thing is its easy to work with JS on those editors .